# Script to load latest R onto a fresh Debian Machine

Tags: r, debian

I'm working on Amazon's Elastic Map Reduce service and I want to bootstrap the latest version of R on to every node. Each node is a pretty basic install of Debian Lenny. I've written a simple shell script that seems to get the job done, but I'm curious if there are better ways or other things I should consider in my script below:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Change these lines if you don't want to use the main CRAN mirror.
# debian R upgrade
echo "deb http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian lenny-cran/" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
echo "deb-src http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian lenny-cran/" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list

# add key to keyring so it doesn't complain 
gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-key 381BA480
gpg -a --export 381BA480 > jranke_cran.asc
sudo apt-key add jranke_cran.asc

# install the latest R
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -t lenny-cran install --yes --force-yes r-base r-base-dev
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks good me!

Two minor hints are

- A newfangled way of adding repos without altering `/etc/apt/sources.list` is to drop a file, say. `cran.list` with the repo information into the subdirectory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`.
- You may not need the `deb-src` line unless you plan to rebuild the packages on those nodes.